# Loading an external JavaScript file without contaminating global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a simple JS file which located at server A, and called from server B (with `<script src="server-A/file.js"></script>` in a page at server B).

In the JS file, I need to use some jQuery functions, so I need to include jQuery, but I don't want to contaminate the global scope of the page, meaning, I want the jQuery `$` I included will be accessed only within my function. Plus, the page might be using its own jQuery (with a different version or not...).

I Googled a lot about it, but kept getting irrelevant results, like how to load files using jQuery (ajax..), how to import jQuery to your page, and stuff.

My code so far:
(Notice: I'm aware of the async loading. The full code will contain callbacks, of course)

```
(function() {
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "http://jq-file.js";       
    document.body.appendChild(jq);

    var otherVar = 123;
    $(...).someFunc();
})();
```

`otherVar` is not accessible outside my plugin (which is good), but jQuery `$` does.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you modify the file you're loading?

Comment: @MikeC -The jQuery I'm trying to load? well, I can keep it on my server and yes, I will be able to modify it.

Comment: So you're creating a plugin that depends on jQuery, and you're going to be distributing said plugin to anybody who wants it? Is that correct? As with 99.99% of other plugins I've come across, you need only advise to the user of the plugin that they must include/require jQuery on their page for your plugin to work. The onus is not on the plugin developer to include jQuery. But maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: @Marcus, you've understood correctly. I do able to guide the user to use jQuery, but I want to know if there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: In my opinion, you need not worry about it. Make a simple statement in your repo addressing the need for jQuery, and that's where it ends. You don't want to load jQuery into your plugin, so don't go that route. Will only stand to bloat your plugin code, and doesn't bode well for caching of the jQuery lib. Short of `alert('jQuery required!')`'ing the user with your plugin that they need to include jQuery (I strongly advise against this), there's not much you can/should do about it.

Comment: OK, I guess this solution is fine. Thanks @Marcus!